# array manipulation, copying last element

Tags: c++

i'm practicing some array manipulation and im wondering why my output is not updating. this should be easy but this is giving me headache. its supposed to be copying the last element to my selected element but no matter what i did my array is not updating. please forgive my noob post. ty

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    char array[20];
    char search;
    int size;

    cout<<"Copy Last Element" <<endl;
    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
    cout<<"Size of the Array: ";
    cin>>size;

    for(int x = 0; x<size; x++){
       cout<<"Enter The elements " <<x+1 <<": ";
       cin>>array[x];
    }

    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
    cout<<"Input Array: ";

    for(int x = 0; x<size; x++){
       cout<<"[" <<array[x] <<"]";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
    cout<<"copy element: ";
    cin>>search;

    for(int x = 0;x<size;x++){
       if(search==array[x]){
          cout<<"Element exist in position  " <<x+1 ;
       }
    }

    search = array[size];

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
    cout<<"New Array: ";

    for(int x =0; x<size; x++){
       cout<<"[" <<array[x] <<"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the input you give the program? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: Also, since you know that array indexes are zero-based, then riddle me this: For an array of `size` elements, what is the top valid index? Think about that while looking at the statement `search = array[size];`.

Comment: Lastly, about the "array is not updating" issue, besides the first loop you never modify the array.

Comment: it's supposed to be copying the last element. for ex. input (a b c) if i input a it will copy the last element (c b c)

Comment: Modifying `search` will not change the array. You need to modify `array[x]` when you find a match.

Comment: thanks for the opinion guys it made sense and i finally figure it out my errors. sorry for not being  clear and thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few observation

- Instead of `char array[20]` you can use `std::vector<int> array` as
  `std::vector<char> array = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
  for(int i = 0; i < array.size();i++) {
         std::cin>>array[i];
  }`
- once this condition `if(search==array[x]){`
  is true you need to replace, but you didn't. Do like

below

```
 for(int x = 0;x<size;x++) {
        if(search==array[x]){ /* if searched ele is found */
                array[x] = array[size-1];/* copy last ele to xth  position */
                cout<<"Element exist in position  " <<x+1 ;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Except that C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you want to suggest that, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: i didn't use vector but i followed your code below and it work. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have this backwards:

```
search = array[size];
```

should be something like:

```
array[size - 1] = search;
```

If you want to assign to last element. And it must be -1 as array starts at 0 index.

Not 100% sure what you want to do from the description, but:

```
array[size - 1] =
```

is how you would assign to last element.

Comment: oh right i overlooked that array[size-1] thanks. what i want to be output is when you input element (a b c) and ask what to copy , it should be copying the last element. ex after you input a b c then i input a, the output should be (c b c) .

Answer (score 0):

If an array has `size` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, size-1]` (ot more correctly `[0, size)`).

It seems you mean the following

```
   cin>>search;
   int i = 0;

   while ( i < size && search != array[i] ) ++i;

   if ( i != size )
   {

        cout<<"Element exist in position  " << i+1 ;

        array[i] = array[size - 1];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin>>search;

for(int x = 0;x<size;x++){
   if(search==array[x]){
      cout<<"Element exist in position  " <<x+1 ;
   }
}

search = array[size];
```

This is your code and I think you want to put the `array[size]` , that is last element in the please of where you have searched. Where `search== array[x]` you have need to use `break` statement then you can put last value in the place of search. Just like this

```
for(int x = 0;x<size;x++){
  if(search==array[x]){
    cout<<"Element exist in position  " <<x ;
    break;
 }
}
array[x]=array[size];
```